# Laptop trackpad acting up

Tags: touchpad, asus-laptop

For reference: ASUS X550L laptop. Windows 10 Home.

My touchpad is behaving in a strange manner. When I lightly hold my finger without moving the mouse cursor jumps around sporadically and even executes left or right clicks. The touchpad is now essentially useless.

It just started happening. I stood up, went out for 30 mins and when I came back this was occurring. I did not close the laptop. No drivers or software was recently installed. No new Windows updates (last driver update took place a month back).

Searching for the issue I mostly find other brand laptop specific advice, turning off mouse cursor precision (which I did) and driver advice.

So, what's going on here?

Comment: Have you cleaned it? Get an external mouse.

Comment: Yes, it's clean. I'm going to restart in safe mode to be 100% on the driver issue. Purchasing a mouse won't explain this phenomena.

Comment: @Gantendo What are the chances that this is physical damage?

Comment: Update BIOS, video driver, and the Mouse Driver. Restart and see if the trackpad is working correctly.